# Prevent Script from Inserting Space in File Name

Tags: bash, shell-script, sql, oracle-database

I have an Oracle database table that is storing the full path and name of a file in a table column.  In a SQL client I can run:

```
select file_name from table where request_id=12345
```

and I will get this result:

```
/home/example_path/example_file_name_1.xls
```

In a bash script I have this statement (which I largely copied from another example I'm working from):

```
# Get Actual Output File Name
VREQID=12345
ATTACH_FILE=$(sqlplus -s $ORA_USER_PSSWD <<-EOQ3
set heading off 
set feedback off 
set pagesize 0 
set sqlprompt "" 
set verify off 
set pause off
select file_name from table where request_id=($VREQID)
/
EOQ3
)
echo 'ATTACH_FILE: ' "$ATTACH_FILE"
# Script continues...
```

My echo statement is then showing:

```
/home/example_path/example_file_name_ 1.xls
```

There's a space between the underscore and the 1.  I've tried using quotes to prevent this but it didn't help.

What is causing this and how do I prevent this?

Comment: Try to add in sql this `set sqlprompt ' '` (single quotes)

Comment: And also try to change `<<-EOQ3` to `<<EOQ3`

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks for suggestion.  I tried both and no change - still have a white space.

Comment: Try also to add this: `set linesize 300`, maybe sqlplus wrap somehow the output. And also `column file_name format a50` may help

Comment: @RomeoNinov SUCCESS!  The answer is adding linesize 300 - apparently it was a wrapping issue.  Thank you!

Comment: Let me add it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine something to do with your SQL query is causing that space because I don't see any bash/shell script related mechanism causing it.  I'm no SQL expert so I can't help there but you have a few shell/bash methods of removing it:

1. Parameter expansion
   *If you call the parameter like so it will remove any spaces:* `"${ATTACH_FILE// /}"`

```bsh
$ ATTACH_FILE='/home/example_path/example_file_name_ 1.xls'
$ echo "${ATTACH_FILE// /}"
/home/example_path/example_file_name_1.xls
```

```bsh
ATTACH_FILE="${ATTACH_FILE// /}"
```

2. Using `tr`
   *You can use `tr` to delete spaces*

```bsh
ATTACH_FILE=$(echo "$ATTACH_FILE" | tr -d ' ')
```

3. Using `sed`
   *You can also use `sed` to delete spaces*

```bsh
ATTACH_FILE=$(echo "$ATTACH_FILE" | sed 's/ //g')
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have added the following to the script and it is effectively removing the whitespace.  It works but still curious if anyone knows the root cause.

                  ATTACH_FILE_NO_WHITESPACE="$(echo -e "${ATTACH_FILE}" | tr -d '[:space:]')"

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments of @RomeoNinov - this was a linesize issue.  The answer was to add

```
 linesize 300
```

before running the sqlplus query.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid string/word wrap you can set the width of the output to big value like 300 symbols:

```
set linesize 300
```

Also for particular column you can define specific format like:

```
column file_name format a50
```

(50 alphanumeric symbols)